# Will setting the connection timeout kill the query on the server side as well?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, timeout

I have some code querying a back-end SQL Server:

```c#
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("PROC1", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;

    try 
    {
       con.Open();
       dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while(dr.Read()) 
       {
          // ...
       }
    }
    catch (SqlException e) 
    {
       // Some logging
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // Some logging
    }
}
```

Once the timeout happens, I am expecting the connection will be closed and the outstanding query will be killed. I am facing an issue where the `tempdb` size has been constant or increasing. Because there are many other processes accessing the same server, I want to ensure that I am not causing this from my end.

When a query timeout occurs, can I expect that SQL Server cleans up and properly kills outstanding queries on the server-side or should I be doing anything more from my side?

Comment: First, tempdb size will be constant unless you turn on auto shrink which is not typically a good practice.  I would spend more time finding time investigating what processes are affecting tempdb.  What is the actual contents of your stored procedure?  Are you sure it's utilizing tempdb?  Second, timeouts do not instantly kill a transactions.  It will have to reach a point where it can be rolled back.  Processes may run beyond the timeout or even become hung.  This is really no different than stopping a query in Management Studio and it takes awhile for it to actual halt.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is, "no".  There might be something you can do in your application, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: @ChrisH: I am using a temporary table to store results from a query initiated to a remote linked server. Sometimes the server takes too long and hence I set a timeout. In a parallel execution environment (where I have 20-30 threads invoking queries), how is this scenario handled?

Comment: How do you set the timeout? Do you use: `EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0` ? After it times out, run `SP_WHO2` on remote server to see if the process is still running. If you are using a temp table: temp tables are stored in tempDB.

Answer (score 3):

When you run any code on the server, the Client stays connected and is waiting for the resposnse from the server.

Timeout - is the maximum time the Client is waiting for response from the Server before closing connection from Client's end. So the code on the server keeps running until it completes or fails (eg. with tempDB overflow error).

So you cannot expect the transaction to terminate upon timeout by default.

Comment: +1 Thank you. What if it is a `SELECT` query and not an exclusive transaction. I have seen that the server (at least when I'm using SQL Server Management Studio) keeps executing the query for some time before it terminates (after I click on the stop button). Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Any statement runs in a transaction. If you do not specify transaction Explicitly, then it is Implicit transaction. After you click stop button SSMS send command to terminate transaction. When Server has available resources it processes that command: it stops execution and cleans up log and tempDB space used for calculations and result set.